# Is it possible to animate settings of primitives?

Tags: animation

In Blender, when you add a primitive (cube, cylinder, etc.), you get some settings at the bottom left corner of the screen, for the number of cuts, the type of cap, etc. However as soon as you perform any other operation, as simple as moving or scaling, those settings are gone for good. I want to make an animation of a cylinder with the number of vertices animated from 3 to say 32, but there's no way to do that with the primitive settings prompt at the bottom left at all. In Cinema 4D, primitives remain primitives until you convert them into a mesh object, and all the settings for primitives remain accessible even after transformation, and even animatable. Is it possible to do the same thing in Blender?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access this kind of history in Blender. But you can use the modifier stack to suit your needs.

[image]

Then add keyframes to animate it :

[image]